# Шахматная ходилка на js

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь написать шахматную ходилку на jquery. Уже заканчивая писать (осталось написать только условие шаха, все фигуры ходят строго по правилам)столкнулся с проблемой. Не могу проверить все возможные варианты шаха. Похоже, я не верно составил схему программы. Хотел бы подвергнуть её Вашей критике.

---

***Схема***

### [image: img]

Немного поясню: 
Функция, происходящая при загрузке странице, распознователь FEN - это положение фигур на доске. 
Функции, происходящие при клике на фигуру:

---

**Шаг 1.** Определяем тип фигуры, х-координату, у-координату и цвет фигуры.

---

**Шаг 2.** Обращаемся к функции которая определяет, куда может почти фигура. *Если эта фигура - король, то мы обращаемся ко всем остальным функциям циклически, проверяя где стоит фигура соперника и куда она может почти. Если ход королём совпадает с ходом фигуры соперника - удаляем координату хода короля.*

---

**Шаг 3.** Преобразем массив с ходами в строку, что бы подставить в плагин sortable.

---

**Шаг 4.** Включаем подсказки, куда можем пойти. Передаем плагину sortable поля, на которые можем пойти. А также в плагине sortable, с обработчиком update(срабатывает при изменении положения текущего объекта) проверяем, не имеет ли чёрная пешка y=1 или белая пешка y=8.

---

**Шаг 5** Совершаем превращение, если сработало условие в шаге 4. Скрываем подсказки.

---

Прошу подсказать на недостатки системы. При таком подходе не могу определить условие шаха.Делаю такую вещь для себя, точнее для своего сайта.

P.S. Коммерческой выгоды от проекта не имею.

Comment: забыли вариант когда король попадает под шах, если сходить другой нашей же фигурой, закрывающей короля в данный момент.

Comment: думаю полезная будет функция "Фигура под боем?". и для каждого хода проверять под боем ли король. для выбранной пользователем фигуры определяем куда она может ходит && не "Король под боем?"  
если сделать цикл по всем своим фигурам и король под боем для любого хода любой фигуры, то мат (если шах и сейчас) или пат (если сейчас шаха нет).

Comment: состояние системы - это когда ход закончен. вот это состояние и надо проверять. в этом состоянии бьют ли нашего короля? т.е. надо проверять не поставил ли соперник шах, а есть ли шах на моем ходу (проверяем текущее состояние) и останется ли шах после моего хода (проверяем возможные ходы).

Comment: @chessinvin, сначала определите под шахом ли король (для определения мата нужно), дальше определяйте возможные ходы для фигуры, выбранной игроком, пусть она может пойти туда-то, теперь для этого хода (для состояния доски после такого хода) определите является ли наш король под шахом или нет. если нет, значит пойти так можно. если нельзя, значит проверяете следущую координату. дальше можете проверить остальные фигуры есть ли у них допустимые ходы, узнаете мат или пат.

Comment: Не забудьте, что король королю не может ставить шах. 

Более общее решение - король не может ходить на битое поле.

Comment: зря вы на sortable это делаете.

Comment: Почему же зря?

Comment: ну не для того он придуман... drag&drop реализуется куда проще.

Comment: Смотрел и такой вариант, проще показался sortable

Comment: Нельзя делать рокировку через битое поле, или из-под шаха.

По теме шахмат – недавно увидел реализацию шахмат на JS – впечатлила скорость. Это был [пример](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/testdrive/demos/chess/) к  asm.js

Answer (score 1):

Думаю **Шаг 2.** стоит пересмотреть. Тут важно учесть куда бьют фигуры, а не куда они ходят. К примеру можно каждый ход держать маску доски, куда фигуры бьют, т.е. на эти клетки королю ходить нельзя.

**из правила выбивается пешка, которая ходит прямо, но кушает по диагонали на одну**

И не забудьте что у короля есть реверс с ладьей, но там тоже дополнительные условия есть.

А в общем алгоритм вроде верный.

Comment: а, немного более понял вашу проблему :) Может и без этой маски можно обойтись. Нужна функция, чтобы проверяла по положению фигур бьет ли противник короля. При построении возможных ходов, надо проверять бьют ли короля (если бьют то это невозможный ход).

> Не очень понял про "Тут важно учесть куда бьют фигуры, а не куда они ходят"

пешка по идеи ходит и бьет в разные стороны.

Comment: если надо определить кем надо ходить, чтобы уйти от шаха - надо проверять все свои фигуры куда они могут ходить, и проверять будет ли шах или нет. Это надо учитывать всегда, потому что любой ход может спровоцировать ситуацию шаха. 

JS код можно кидать [сюда][1], но лично я не хочу в них разбираться, могу только общий алгоритм помочь понять и составить )

[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Понял идею, сейчас буду пытаться реализовать. Уже предчувствую проблему возвращения фигуры на прежнее место тем способом, который описал Юрий...

Comment: не надо передвигать и возвращать ничего. у вас должно быть:

* реальное состояние доски перед ходом, которое сменится только после реального хода.
* виртуальное состояние доски после хода определенной фигуры на определенную позицию. таких состояний будет столько сколько фигур и сколько разных ходов они могут сделать плюс рокировка (когда две фигуры перемещаются).

все эти состояния вам надо будет прогнать через "Король под боем?", получите можно сходить/мат/пат.  
ЗЫ полный перебор всех состояний каждый раз - объект оптимизации, некоторые состояния потом нужно будет научиться не проверять.

Comment: реальное состояние доски перед ходом - такое имеется (т.е. кто где стоит).
виртуальное состояние доски после хода определенной фигуры на определенную позицию - как её получить? 
-------------
чём будет являться состояние доски? строкой фен или многомерным массивом вида array[n(конь)][поле, на которое можем пойти]?

Comment: после реального хода виртуальное состояние станет реальным простым копированием. соответственно какое у вас реальное такое же должно быть и виртуальное, т.е. копия реального с выполненным ходом. как у вас там хранится реальное я не знаю, может хэшмэп, может массив 8x8...

Comment: Понял. Спасибо. Постараюсь реализовать!